# React Native AsyncStorage save multiple items

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

Is it possible to save multiple items with same key with AsyncStorage?
I have a ListView with multiple item that can be added to favorites, when the user presses the 'add to favs' button it executes this code:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(item.CodViatura));
```

But if I want to add another item, it will replace the previous one. How can I add more than one with the same key? So I can call this code on favorites screen:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then((cod)=>{
  this.setState({value: JSON.parse(cod)}
  });
})
```

I know I can use realm for data management but I found it harder than AsyncStorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store array of items

```
AsyncStorage
  .getItem('key')
  .then(favs => {
      favs = favs == null ? [] : JSON.parse(favs)

      favs.push(item.CodViatura)

      return AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(favs))
  })
```

Comment: that is the code to set the item right? It's not working, doesn't store any item.

Comment: @waze Well, it should. Try to add `catch` to see if something fails. Also try adding `.then(() => AsyncStorage.getItem('key')).then(x => console.log(x))` to check it actually stores something.

Comment: Im getting this error: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
favs.push is not a function`

Comment: You have already something in your storage that was not an array. Remove it first. Or add `favs = Array.isArray(favs) ? favs : [favs]` before pushing

Comment: thank you! I got it! do I need anything special to get the items and show them?

Comment: Nothing special to get Items `AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then(JSON.parse).then(items => /*use items*/)` other than now items is array potentially containing multiple values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, im accepting the answer.